# Count number of occurrences (or frequency) in a sorted array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, flowchart

May someone take a look at my block diagram? I wanna make sure there's no any mistake. I'm sorry for foreign-polish names used in the code but I haven't planned before to share the code anywhere. The program counts number of occurrences (or frequency) in a sorted array. I wanted to keep the time complexity as low as possible so I used binary search.
For ease of read the diagram I can explain/translate some of the elements: l - first index of a searching list, p - last index of a searching list, licz -> count, pierwszy->first , ostatni->last, w - it's the searching number in the array, n - length of the array.

```
[https://codepen.io/patryk2205/pen/RwGzEpX][1]
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU1SS.png][2]


  [1]: https://codepen.io/patryk2205/pen/RwGzEpX
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU1SS.png
```

Comment: There is not that much code, so would it be too much effort to translate the code to use English names and comments (in the code itself)?

Comment: Alrgiht, give me a sec. I'll translate it.

Comment: Do you want us to check if the code is correct? Or there's some issue and you can't figure that out?

Comment: There's the block diagram in the link as well as code.

Comment: Ok, guys, I translated names used in the code as I could. I'm sure that the code itself works. I'd like you to check if the block diagram to this code is either right